# Is their a way to code a button that will function as a live button

Tags: vb.net

I have been thinking about how to code a button, that will take the text in my label to the screen. The button will work as a live button, so whenever it is been clicked, it will send it to the second screen. So, it will be projected.
And also I want to make my text in the label box fall into the next line and create paragraph.
E.g

```
Label1.text = "I am a Boy, I love my Mother"
```

But I want the result to be in this way -

```
I am a Boy  
I love my Mother.
```

Instead of it, wrapping the texts

Please help me out masters

Comment: It's not at all clear to us what you mean when you talk about screens. We need actual code and controls to use for context.

Comment: Your question is rather nonsensical.  There's no such thing as a "live button".  When you click a `Button`, it raises its `Click` event.  That's it.  You handle that event in your form and then add code to do whatever you want.  If that is get text from a `Label` and do something with it then by all means do that.  If your question is actually how to do something specific with that text then that's what your question should be focusing on, not the `Button`.

Comment: Perhaps you are talking about more than one monitor?

Comment: The label on the second screen should be in a form, of course. You can set the label's Dock property to Fill if it's the only control on the Form then set the `Label.AutoSize` to True.

Comment: I also think the `Live Button` concept comes from `Easy Worship presentation software`. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Label1.text = "I am a Boy" & vbcrlf & "I love my Mother"
```